How make eclipse quick search for a particular string in specific file types
I want to search for a specific string, say "active", in .css or .javascript files and and the search should exclude .java and .html files.
How to achieve it using regex?
I tried *css|*js but it did not worked.

Tried *css,*js. It worked.
Regex syntax to search in multiple files : <file_1_suffix>,<file_2_suffix>
